# Suspend not working due to backlight issue

Tags: ati, xorg, suspend, backlight, 14.04

I am using the `Radeon HD 6320` video card with the radeon xorg driver.  I have tried using the `flgrx dirver` but it isn't as snappy as the xorg and also has brightness issues.

The `xorg driver` has issues with Suspend thought and I believe I have tracked it down to a backlight issue.  I have used pm-suspend and everything comesback on except for the screen.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find info on this problem [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42960). I resolved the issue on my system (HP Pavilion m6-1035dx w/ AMD Trinity A10-4600M APU) by creating a file **/etc/pm/config.d/radeon** containing the following:

```
QUIRK_S3_BIOS="true"
QUIRK_S3_MODE="true"
```

Then reboot.

If this doesn't resolve the problem for you, then check out the link that I gave at the top.

Comment: That worked thanks! I tried `pm-suspend --quirks...` in the command line but that didn't work.  What would be the difference?